# PlPlot and Javafx

Tags: java, javafx, swig, fxml, pane

I have started using JavaFX for one of my GUI application which requires scientific plotting of 3D contour etc. For the plotting routine, I thought to use PlPlot which can be used with Java and which plots 3D plots, contours etc. I can plot my data in a separate "X-Window" using PlPlot while I need to place the plot in a JavaFX `Pane`, say `AnchorPane`. I may use PLPlot commands like following:

```
PLStream pls = new PLStream();
pls.sdev("xwin");
pls.init();
pls.env(col1Min, col1Max, col2Min, col2Max, 0, 0);
pls.line(col1, col2);
pls.end();
```

I see plot appears in a separate X-Window as it would be while I need to place in a `Pane`. The device declaration by `pls.sdev("xwin")` does not return any handle as shown in manual.

Can you kindly provide any idea?
Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jzy3d is able to draw [contour plots](http://jzy3d.org/gallery.php) and there are tools to [customize](http://doc.jzy3d.org/javadoc/0.9.1/jzy3d-api/org/jzy3d/chart/factories/ContourChartComponentFactory.html) contours.

I demonstrate how to run Jzy3d charts in JavaFX [here](https://github.com/jzy3d/jzy3d-api/blob/master/jzy3d-javafx/src/main/java/org/jzy3d/demos/javafx/DemoJzy3dFX.java).

Comment: Martin, you may wish to edit all of your jzy3d answers to mention your affiliation with the project (if there is one).  See [How can I link to an external resource in a community-friendly way?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022/how-can-i-link-to-an-external-resource-in-a-community-friendly-way).

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks a lot. Those were really nice plots.

Comment: @Martin, I have seen that in your demo, you have used  ` import org.jzy3d.javafx.JavaFXChartFactory;
import org.jzy3d.javafx.JavaFXRenderer3d;
import org.jzy3d.javafx.controllers.JavaFXCameraMouseController; `. However, in the repository I did not find jar for javafx. Can you kindly point me? Thanks.

Comment: @vegaonline sorry, I fixed the upload :) http://maven.jzy3d.org/snapshots/org/jzy3d/jzy3d-javafx/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/

Comment: @vegaonline I am also investigating charts using core JavaFX 3d shapes : https://github.com/jzy3d/FXyz-1/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jzy3d/demos/javafx/DemoJzy3dFX.java. Still little problems with axes, but this is promising. However the above mentioned JavaFX binding should do the job faster.

Comment: @Martin, Sorry to bother you. Your work is really impressive and I am trying to use it. As soon as I am declaring `JavaFXChartFactory factory = new JavaFXChartFactory();`  I find that it reports error as if class not found. Can you help me to see which is missing.? I am using all the jar files provided and declared in libraries of the application. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since the OP is looking for any ideas, here is a trick (maybe it is not the best choice, but it will work fine).

1. Save your plot as `.png` file using pngcairo (Cairo PNG Driver).
2. Load the image to a JLabel in your pane:

```
JLabel  lblPic = new javax.swing.JLabel();
lblPic.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("output.png"));
```